# Angular how to make PUT before GET action (file download)?

Tags: angularjs

I had nice working file download via get

```
<a ng-href="path/to/get/pdf/including/{{ angularVariables }}" >Export to PDF</a>
```

But currently I need to make an update action before executing get, what would be the best approach to do it?

I've tried to to add ng-click action in which I make put request, but I couldn't figure out how to wait with get action till put returns. Ideally it would be something like this:

```
// template 
<a ng-href="path/to/get/pdf/including/{{ angularVariables }}" ng-click="updatePDF()" >Export to PDF</a>

// controller
$scope.updatePDF = function () {
  stop_click
  myService.update(params, function(resp) {
    continue_click
  });
}
```

Is this even possible? If not, how to solve this problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: maybe calling $window.open after service returns

Comment: I've checked this as a possible solution, but it opens download in a new window and gets blocked by the browser (or rather browser blocks it and asks if it should allow popups from current page). With just a link I didn't have this problems...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$location.path` and set path in success method of service call.

Try something like

```
// template 
<a ng-href="#" ng-click="updatePDF()" >Export to PDF</a>

// controller
$scope.updatePDF = function () {
  myService.update(params, function(resp) {
    $location.path('YourPath')
  });
}
```

See [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

Comment: I've tried that too - I get redirected and I only wanted to download a file, have browser file download dialog opened and don't move from the current page...

Comment: ok it worked with using location.href = 'YourPAth' (not $location)... I don't think that it's angular-way, but it works...